# Custom Decorators in Tornado

Tags: python, tornado, decorator, python-decorators

I'm facing an error while trying to make a custom tornado decorator.

```
TypeError: post() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

The sample code is:

```
def decorate( function_name ):
    # Do something
    function_name()
    # Do something

class MainHandler( tornado.web.RequestHandler ):
    @decorate
    def post( self ):
        # Do whatever
```

How do I pass the context of `self` to the decorator ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you're not passing the arguments from the decorator to the decorated method.

Here's how your decorator should look like:

```
def decorate(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # pass the received arguments to
        # the decorated function
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```